# Retrieving value from object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I cant get the value out of *[Create Table]* because of the space.

I create the object like this...

```
$create_table = DB::select('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table_name)[0];
```

And this is what the object looks like...

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Table] => contact_monitor
    [Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `contact_monitor` (
        `contact_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        `monitor_id` int(11) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
)
```

However, I can get the value out of *[Table]* using `$create_table->Table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `{}` curly brace to access those properties with spaces:

```
echo $create_table->{'Create Table'}; // this will also work on hyphenated properties as well
```

Comment: @itsliamoco sure no prob! glad this helped